# Variable width columns in angular-grid

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-grid

I'm using [AngularGrid](http://angulargrid.com/index.html) to show a grid with several fixed width columns. The grid itself should take the whole page, except for the left column of the page. That part works, using a css `calc`.

Now, I want one of the grid columns to fill up the rest of the available width inside the grid. Is it possible to do that with ag-grid built ins?

HTML:

```
<div ag-grid="gridOptions" style="height: 500px; width: calc(100% - 150px)"></div>
```

Script:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [{
    headerName: 'First',
    width: 150
  }, {
    headerName: 'Second',
    width: // whatever is available (should be calc(100% - 250px))
  }, {
    headerName: 'Third',
    width: 100
  }]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190909/html-table-column-widths-combining-fixed-and-variable-widths

Comment: Doesn't help, `ag-grid` is not a table.

Comment: Do you need a responsible layout?